# Is there a way to display full-width spaces in Notepad ++

Tags: notepad++, whitespace, removing-whitespace

I am currently using Notepad++ v6.8.8 programming in both Japanese and English for a variety of languages (mainly Java, SQL and HTML/CSS).

Due to having to change keyboard layouts whilst coding, occasionally full-width characters manage to get put in the code (spaces, numbers and English letters). With the "Show Whitespace and TAB" option selected, half-width spaces appear as a dot with tabs appearing as a rightwards facing arrow. Japanese input full-width spaces ("　") [[U+3000](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/3000/index.htm)] appear as just a blank space without any indication they are present, however both full-width numbers are easily discernible (due to the fact that the letters and numbers are stretched, and they raise errors).

Both the following settings do not display full-width whitespace.

> View > Show Symbol > Show Whitespace and TAB
>   View > Show Symbol > Show All Characters

**Is there a way to display full-width spaces (and other full-width blank characters)?**

Comment: The 3 bytes 0xE3 0x80 and 0x80 occur between the quotes of `("　")` in the question.

Comment: @AdrianHHH Because it is a Unicode space. It shows as U+3000 CJK Symbols and Punctuation. Were you trying to clarify something? Or just making a statement?

Comment: The question just shows gap between the quotes, the actual character(s) there are not specified precisely. I thought that it may help someone to know the hex codes of the bytes in the gap.

Comment: @AdrianHHH The specific UTF8 Hex bytes should not be of much importance. Nevertheless, I have included it's FileFormat page as a link.